# How to ensure that there is no MAC address conflict using Virtualbox?

Tags: mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos, virtualization

I want to set up cluster of 5 machines on Virtualbox; the Host OS is Windows 10 and Guest OS are all CentOS 6.8.

I created a virtual server with name `base` and did all the necessary configuration, software needed.

Once this `base` image is ready, I cloned off other instance from this `base image`.

The problem which I faced is that in all these images the MAC address is same, and although I did `refresh` to make them distinct , however inadverantly I missed some of the instances.

My question is:

Is there any way to guarantee that these virtual servers have different MAC addresses (when cloned from same machine)

Comment: Of course it is. Have you missed the "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards" checkbox in VBox GUI when cloning?

Comment: @MarekRost:  Yes I have seen that "Reinitialize..." things. Does that guarantee that the MAC address is unique for all the virtual servers that are in Virtualbox? Does that reinitialize the one which are created now or earlier as well?

Comment: it will generate new random MAC for the newly created machine - so there is reasonable chance it will be unique. Alternatively you can set MAC manually from machine settings -> network -> adapter -> advanced. Obviously it won't work from inside the machine unless you change it with every boot.